# Getting full month with day and description

Tags: javascript, html, date, dayofweek

I want to be able to get a pop up screen which shows every day of the current month and which day (of the week) it is.

It would look like this:

- Thursday 1/10/2015
- Friday 2/10/2015
- . . .

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="navigation1.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <button onclick="getDaysInMonth()">try it</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var nacht = "nacht";
    var morgen = "morgen";
    var middag = "middag";
    var avond = "avond";
```

This is an array with the max days of each month

```js
    var dagenInMaand = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];
    var year = d.getYear();
    var month = d.getMonth();

        var d = new Date();
        var t = d.getHours();           
        if(t >= '0' && t <= '6'){
            var g = nacht;
        }else if(t >= '6' && t <= '9'){
            var g = morgen;
        }else if(t >= '9' && t <= '17'){
            var g = middag;
        }else{
            var g = avond;
        }
```

These are my days of the week but it is originally from another function but it doesn't want to work anymore

```js
        var j = d.getDay();
        if(j == '1'){
            var a = "Maandag"
        }else if(j == '2'){
            var a = "dinsdag"
        }else if(j == '3'){
            var a = "woensdag"
        }else if(j == '4'){
            var a = "donderdag"
        }else if(j == '5'){
            var a = "vrijdag"
        }else if(j == '6'){
            var a = "zaterdag"
        }else{
            var a = "zondag"
        }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Goede " + g + ", het is vandaag " + a + ".";

    function getDaysOfWeekDescription()
    {

    }

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet ?

Comment: if you have some code, we can [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i have some code but the days of the weak wil be in dutch

Comment: Maybe this bit helps - you have to format dates before push to array
http://jsfiddle.net/jL9resy1/

Answer (score 0):

Based on what Malith McR commented, here's an updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jL9resy1/1/

This builds the array.  It currently alerts it, but can modify your popup to handle the array any way you choose.

```
var weekday = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday",
               "Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]; //these are obviously in english

function getDaysInMonth() {
         var date = new Date();
         var days = [];
         while (date.getMonth()) {
            days.push(weekday[date.getDay()] + " "  + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' +  date.getFullYear());
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
         }
         return days;
    }

alert(getDaysInMonth());
```

Comment: @Sanscull, does that mean you'll approve the answer?

Comment: yes a litlle i only now need to get that he takes from the first day of the current month to the last day of the current month

Comment: @Sanscull, please accept at your earliest convenience.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var d = new Date();

var t = d.getHours();           
if(t >= '0' && t <= '6'){
    var g = "nacht";
}else if(t >= '6' && t <= '9'){
    var g = "morgen";
}else if(t >= '9' && t <= '17'){
    var g = "middag";
}else{
    var g = "avond";
}
var dagen = {
    1 : "maandag",
    2 : "dinsdag",
    3 : "woensdag",
    4 : "donderdag",
    5 : "vrijdag", 
    6 : "zaterdag",
    0 : "zondag"
};
var maanden = {
    0 : "januari",
    1 : "februari",
    2 : "maart",
    3 : "april",
    4 : "mei", 
    5 : "juni",
    6 : "juli",
    7 : "augustus",
    8 : "september",
    9 : "oktober",
    10 : "november", 
    11 : "december"
};
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Goede " + g + ", het is vandaag " + dagen[d.getDay()] + " " + d.getDate() + " "  + maanden[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getFullYear() +".";
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

I think this is what you mean with getting the date.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qL5zwnz4/